# How can you call the offset operator on a pointer to an object in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

In my code I have a class like this

```
#include <iostream>

//Not my real code

class SomeClass
{
    operator[] (int integer);
}

SomeClass::operator[] (int integer)
{
    return integer;
}
```

I can create an instance of this on the stack and use the offset operator method like this.

```
SomeClass instance;
std::cout << instance[1];
```

But if I use heap memory with a pointer I have only been able to do this

```
SomeClass *instance = new SomeClass();
std::cout << instance->operator[](1);
```

I have tried dereferencing it like this with the error "indirection requires pointer opperand"

```
SomeClass *instance = new SomeClass();
std::cout << *instance[1];
```

Is there a way I can use the operator method implicitly on a pointer to an object?

Comment: Keep operator precedence in mind. And it's `operator[]`. That's just a function, so you can call it like a function.

Comment: like `(*instance)[i]`

Comment: No, since pointers must first be dereferenced using one of the dereference operators (`->`, `*`) first. I'd suggest implementing an `at()` member function which is prettier to look at; thus, `std::cout << instance->at(1)`

Comment: @mnunberg: Conventional wisdom (aka the standard) has it that such àn `at` member function must perform bounds-checking, while `operator[]` need not.

Comment: That's right so I would use (*instance)[1] thanks

Comment: You don't actually *need* to use `new`. `new` is considered harmful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to de-ref with the * operator and then just use it. As per the comment by sp2danny.

```
std::cout << (*instance)[1];
```